# How can I add multiple static html elements before the div class='App' in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to add 3 empty divs before the  of my reactjs web page for special styling reasons, but I get an error if I do that:

Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

What I need is

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div class='App'> 
...
</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you paste in your current app code

Comment: Did you try it in the index.html file in the public folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message contains the details you need:

> Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

This means you need to wrap your elements in a [JSX fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), like so:

```
<>
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div class='App'> 
    ...
  </div>
</>
```

Note that `<>...</>` is simply shorthand for `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are trying to return multiple JSX elements which is not how React works

You are trying to do this:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div class='App'> 
...
</div>
```

But react will expect that you return single div with all the elemets inside, so pretty much all you need to do is to wrap them all in one div like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div class='App'> 
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why add an unwanted `div` when you can just use a fragment?

Comment: or you can use something called React.Fragmet or <> </>, i would definitly google more about that one, but wrapping this into one simple div as i showed you above will be completly enough for now

Comment: @LionelRowe if anyone would show me fragments when i first started i would be like "... wait but why" so , i would rather use divs and then later on i would learn about fragments and what problem does this solve

Comment: @Drizz159 "i would rather use divs and then later on i would learn about fragments and what problem does this solve" I think the use case for fragments is pretty simple. If you want to create an additional DOM node, use a `div`. If you don't, use a fragment. Given that the question relates to styling, it's quite possible that adding an additional parent node would break some CSS.

Comment: @LionelRowe I agree, it is pretty easy and straight forward what <></> or React.Fragment does, but i still think that it could be overwhelming why you need this and what this actualy does in your virtual DOM in your beginnings